# How to sort the file based on last column in unix using sort command?

Tags: sorting

```
a 1
b 2 4
c 3
d 4 5 7
e 4 6
f 5
```

how can we print the output like below using `sort` in which the last column is sorted -

```
a 1
c 3
b 2 4
f 5
e 4 6
d 4 5 7
```

We can achieve the result using awk -

```
$awk '{print $NF,$0}' file.txt | sort -n | cut -f2- -d' '
a 1
c 3
b 2 4
f 5
e 4 6
d 4 5 7
```

Comment: When the data does not have an equal number of columns in each row, that (or something very similar) would seem to be the best solution. Here's some further discussion: http://www.unixcl.com/2010/11/sort-file-based-on-last-field-unix.html

Comment: @Vipin, did our comments, posts help you? Please do let us know on same, so that others could learn from this post too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 -Thanks for checking on it, I was looking for a sort only solution (Without Pipe) but looks like above output is not possible to achieve from sort command only without a pipe, we have to use awk or rev to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
rev Input_file | sort -nk1.1  | rev
```